# How to find a containing shape in visio?

Tags: vb.net, visio

Is there a way to find out the containing shape in Visio using VB.NET? Example - There a rectangle and within it is a circle. If a user selects a circle, is it possible to find / get the containing rectangle in code?

The way I'm solving this issue right now is I ask user to select both Rectangle, loop through selected shapes, get the properties of rectangle and then deselect the rectangle. Ultimate goal is to repeat the shape within the rectangle to fill the rectangle.

Any better ways to do this?

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 0):

The Parent property will tell you what shape contains another shape.  If the shape is not part of a group, the Parent will be the parent page (really the PageSheet for the parent page).

The ContainingShape property tells you the highest-level parent shape for a grouped shape. So if a shape is grouped n-levels deep, ContainingShape will tell you the root shape.

Comment: Thanks ! The issue was that the rectangle and the control inside it were not grouped. However, I don't want user to group them. It will be one extra step and annoying too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SpatialSearch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff765899.aspx) method. 
That is, if shapes are not grouped then Visio needs to analyze the drawing to find the related shapes. Note that this method is a bit slower than grouping and then using `Parent` property.

You could also consider using containers. The container shapes are special type of shapes to contain other shapes, with easy API to get members/parents. [Read more about container shapes here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff959245.aspx). Means, don't use plain "rectangle" to "group" shapes, use a "container" shape instead. It has a lot of nice features.

Comment: Guess what I did? I dragged a rectangle to my stencil, then renamed that rectangle to "myrectangle". Then I get it in code by its name.